# Haskell Regex - Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘IO () error

Tags: haskell

Within Haskell I have a program that **scrapes** the html off a page and stores it in a variable called 'html' which is type IO (). I then want to generate a list of type String that holds all the matches by a pattern from that web page.

These two lines below generate a list of matches from the pattern

```
let pattern = "..." --note, regex is omited
html =~ pattern :: String -> IO String
```

I get the error:

[image]

What I want to do is something like:

```
 let pattern = "..." 
 let matches_list = html =~ pattern :: String -> IO String
```

Where matches_list of type String is a list of matches.

**EDIT**

---

The actual **scraper** which I got from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup) works simply like this:

[image]

Imagine 'src' is my 'html' variable

Comment: If `html` is of type `IO ()` then it is not a value in the traditional sense, but it is an IO action much like a C function with prototype `void html(void)` (if that helps).  First you need to get the HTML, which it seems you are not doing.

Comment: Also, in these sorts of questions it is always helpful if you link to the library you are using.  For regular expressions there is no single library that dominates the Haskell ecosystem.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson please see my edit

Comment: "These two lines below generate a list of matches from the pattern" - apparently they don't.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast the result of the regular expression matcher into a function that takes a string and returns an `IO String`, but based on your description, it sounds like you'd rather just cast it into a list of strings, and although you haven't specified what regular expression library you are using, your fix is probably as simple as changing this:

```haskell
let matches_list = html =~ pattern :: String -> IO String
```

into this:

```haskell
let matches_list = html =~ pattern :: [String]
```